# I can't go to another activity from button click

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm creating a new android application and want to go to another new activity when the button clicked. what should i need to code?

```
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    reg = findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    uname = findViewById(R.id.uname);
    pass = findViewById(R.id.pass);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 ArrayList < User > list = dbHelper.readAllInfo();

 for (User u: list) {
  if (u.getUserName().equals(uname.getText().toString())) {
   if (u.getPassword().equals(pass.getText().toString())) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, ProfileManagement.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", u.getUserId());
    startActivity(intent);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I expect to go to ProfileManagement class. But it didn't work

**Here is another intent i used**

```
reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {

  String user = uname.getText().toString();
  String passwrd = pass.getText().toString();

  dbHelper.addInfo(user, passwrd);

  Toast.makeText(Home.this, "User Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you really reach the place where you start the activity? Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to temporarily execute the Intent without any condition first?
I think your intents is OK, but something from your database conditions is returning False, and the Intent is not executing:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, ProfileManagement.class);
    //intent.putExtra("id", u.getUserId());
    startActivity(intent);

   }
  }
```

Also, make sure you have both activities declared on your Manifest.